# Compress page causes issue while postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, compression

I am using this link to compress aspx page
http://terrapinstation.wordpress.com/2008/06/12/aspnet-http-comression-and-reducing-response-size.

However this cause issue while postback from buttons in update panel.
What might be possible solution?

One of workaround is to move button out of update panel, but is there a way to do it keeping button inside update panel?

Comment: You might have to specify your issues a bit closer. And what did you exactly implement from that page?

Comment: After compression, my page has issue in redirecting to other page when button is in update panel..

Comment: Is the redirect on the server or on the client? What happens exactly? Try fiddle to tell you wants going on behind the scenes.
Do you have javascript errors?

Comment: where do i add global.asax code in jsfiddle?, no js errors

Comment: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.

Comment: Did you turn off viewstate?